# firefox browser showing extra 1page before content when printing with jqueryprint.js

Tags: jquery, css, html, printing

I am trying to print a portion of an HTML page with dynamic content by php with a big space as header because that portion should be empty when printing  for something else after printing . After so many tries I got perfect result for chrome but the fire is not printing like chrome .

why firefox is adding an extra page before ? with no content it is ok . but if i add any content or height for the div or margin its adding extra page with printing the header only .

The HTML code stucture for print is

```
    <section class="panel" id="payablePrint">
   <table>
    <thead >
      <tr>
        <th style="width:100%">
           <div id="print_header"style="opacity: 0.001;">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
           </div>
        </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
          <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
               <th>Firstname</th>
               <th>Lastname</th> 
               <th>Age</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Jill</td>
              <td>Smith</td> 
              <td>50</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td>Jackson</td> 
              <td>94</td>
           </tr>
    </table>
       </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
        <td>
           footer here....,.
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
   </table>
   </section>
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
     <button id="" onclick="printDiv('payablePrint')"  class="btn btn-shadow btn-primary jdIconButton"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print Agreement</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

and css for this is

```
 @media print{

 #print_header{
   display: block;
  }
  #Footer{
  display: none !important;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  }
  #printFooter {
  display: block;
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 154px;
  }
 .panel-footer{
  border-top: none !important;
 }
 /* *************** */
 thead { display: block; page-break-after: avoid;page-break-before: avoid;}
 table { page-break-after:auto; }
 tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
 td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto; }
 thead { display:table-header-group; page-break-before: avoid;}
 tboby { display: table-row-group;page-break-after: avoid;page-break-before: avoid;}
 tfoot { display:table-footer-group;}
/* *************** */

 #footer {
  display: block; 
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0;
}
#companyName{
  margin-top: -10px !important; 
}
.panel-body{ 
  margin: -1mm 0mm 10mm 0mm !important;

}

.agreement_title{
  margin-top: -15px !important;
}
.margin_top{
  margin-top: -6px !important;
}

}
```

why firefox is adding an extra page before ? with no content it is ok . but if i add any content or height for the div or margin its adding extra page with the header only .
Any kind of help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Use colspan and rowspan as your need. Remove the children table that within the main table. Please check the below code..

```html
    <section class="panel" id="payablePrint">
   <table>
    <thead >
      <tr>
        <th style="width:100%">
           <div id="print_header"style="opacity: 0.001;">
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
           </div>
        </th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
            content goes here ......
        </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
     <tr>
        <td>
           footer here....,.
        </td>
     </tr>
    </tfoot>
   </table>
   </section>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 text-right">
      <button id="" onclick="printDiv('payablePrint')"  class="btn btn-shadow btn-primary jdIconButton"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print Agreement</button>
     </div>
   </div>
```